# {N} Load ImageSource `fromData` on Android

Tags: nativescript

The following code to programmatically create an Image view works on iOS but results in a runtime error on Android (Fire OS 5.4.0.0). Any ideas on where/why this fails?

```
var http = require("http");
var imageModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/image");
var imageSourceModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");

function buildImageView() {
  return http.request({ url: "https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300", method: "GET" })
    .then(function (response) {
      var result = imageSourceModule.fromData(response.content.raw);
      if (!result) throw new Error("Unable to load content into ImageSource.");
      var imageView = new imageModule.Image();
      imageView.src = result;
      return imageView;
    });
}
```

When wrapping with `console.log` messages it seems the error is occurring in `imageSourceModule.fromData`.

The output in the `tns run android --device {deviceid}` is:

```
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:72]     from java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[])
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:72]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native method)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:72]   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1021)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:72]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:903)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:72]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:890)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:72]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:874)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:72]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:866)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native method)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1021)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:903)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:890)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:874)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:866)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native method)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1021)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:903)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:890)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:874)
F/art     (30821): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:866)
```

F/art indeed! Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue. On Android, `response.content.raw` is a `java.io.OutputStream`. `ImageSource.loadFromData` calls `android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream` which accepts a `java.io.InputStream`.

It would be nice if NativeScript had a platform independent and directionally independent way of representing data like `Blob` or `Buffer` — `Blob` being preferable because it maintains and transports the content's media type information along with the data.

I've modified the above example to show how to resolve the issue:

```
var http = require("http");
var platform = require("platform");
var imageModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/image");
var imageSourceModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");

function buildImageView() {
  return http.request({ url: "https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300", method: "GET" })
    .then(function (response) {
      var result;

      if (platform.isAndroid) {
        var inputStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(response.content.raw.toByteArray());
        result = android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
      } else {
        result = imageSourceModule.fromData(response.content.raw);
      }

      if (!result) throw new Error("Unable to load content into ImageSource.");

      var imageView = new imageModule.Image();
      imageView.src = result;
      return imageView;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use toImage for the response content.

```
function buildImageView() {
    return http.request({ url: "https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300", method: "GET" })
        .then(function (response) {

            response.content.toImage().then(function(res) {
                // res is image
                console.log(res.width); // 200
                console.log(res.height) // 300
            })

        });
}
```

Keep in mind that when working with URLs that are directly pointing to an image the best practice is to directly assign the string to the `src` and avoid using imageSource. More information about this [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/images-optimisations)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm focused specifically on how to get `fromData` to work on Android with the value obtained from `response.content.raw`. This code only paraphrases the real issue for reproduction purposes. I don't think I'd be able to incorporate this answer into the real solution.